# Jenkins build from tag using Bitbucket Branch Source plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I would like to build my jenkins pipeline when I create a tag in master branch in bitbucket. I have jenkins building on commit of master branch, but I can not seem to get it to build for creation of a tag.

This is what I have so far:

```
stage('Update DEV ECS') {
  when { branch 'dev' }
  steps {
    script{
      withAWS(region:'us-east-1') {
        def outputs = cfnUpdate(stack: 'DEV-TARGETDB-SERVICE',
          params:["ImageUrl=${env.FULL_ECR_URL}"],
          keepParams:[
            'EnvVarName1',
            'EnvVarValue1',
            'EnvVarName2',
            'EnvVarValue2',
            'EnvVarName3',
            'EnvVarValue3',
            'ContainerCpu',
            'ContainerMemory',
            'ContainerPort',
            'DatabaseHost',
            'DatabaseName',
            'DatabasePassword',
            'DatabaseUser',
            'DesiredCount',
            'HttpCode',
            'HTTPSListener',
            'Path',
            'Priority',
            'Role',
            'TaskRole',
            'ServiceName',
            'StackName',
            'DataDogAPIKey',
            'TaskCpu',
            'TaskMemory'
          ],
          timeoutInMinutes:15,
          pollInterval:1000)
      }
    }
  }
}

stage('Update TEST ECS') {
  when { branch 'master' }
  steps {
    script{
      withAWS(region:'us-east-1') {
        def outputs = cfnUpdate(stack: 'TEST-TARGETDB-SERVICE',
          params:["ImageUrl=${env.FULL_ECR_URL}"],
          keepParams:[
            'EnvVarName1',
            'EnvVarValue1',
            'EnvVarName2',
            'EnvVarValue2',
            'EnvVarName3',
            'EnvVarValue3',
            'ContainerCpu',
            'ContainerMemory',
            'ContainerPort',
            'DatabaseHost',
            'DatabaseName',
            'DatabasePassword',
            'DatabaseUser',
            'DesiredCount',
            'HttpCode',
            'HTTPSListener',
            'Path',
            'Priority',
            'Role',
            'TaskRole',
            'ServiceName',
            'StackName',
            'DataDogAPIKey',
            'TaskCpu',
            'TaskMemory'
          ],
          timeoutInMinutes:15,
          pollInterval:1000)
      }
    }
  }
}

stage('Update PROD ECS') {
  when {
    branch 'master'
    tag 'v*'
  }
  steps {
    script{
      withAWS(region:'us-east-1') {
        def outputs = cfnUpdate(stack: 'PROD-TARGETDB-SERVICE',
          params:["ImageUrl=${env.FULL_ECR_URL}"],
          keepParams:[
            'EnvVarName1',
            'EnvVarValue1',
            'EnvVarName2',
            'EnvVarValue2',
            'EnvVarName3',
            'EnvVarValue3',
            'ContainerCpu',
            'ContainerMemory',
            'ContainerPort',
            'DatabaseHost',
            'DatabaseName',
            'DatabasePassword',
            'DatabaseUser',
            'DesiredCount',
            'HttpCode',
            'HTTPSListener',
            'Path',
            'Priority',
            'Role',
            'TaskRole',
            'ServiceName',
            'StackName',
            'DataDogAPIKey',
            'TaskCpu',
            'TaskMemory'
          ],
          timeoutInMinutes:15,
          pollInterval:1000)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The dev and prod stages work, but the prod stage does not work. I don't even see a job in jenkins for the prod stage (I do for dev and master). There is a "tags" section under the project in jenkins, but it is empty.

Comment: If you use multibranch pipeline, have you added 'Discover tags' in Behaviours section of Branch Sources configuration?

Answer (score 1):

When you checkout a Git repository, you checkout either by branch or by tag, but not both. When Jenkins checks out a branch, it sets up *BRANCH_NAME* variable to the name of the checked out branch; when it checks out a tag it [sets](https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/branch/BranchNameContributor.java) *TAG_NAME* **and** *BRANCH_NAME* to the name of the tag.

The [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) says:

> If the when directive contains more than one condition, all the child conditions must return true for the stage to execute.

The *tag* condition matches *TAG_NAME*, while *branch* condition matches *BRANCH_NAME* so they both need to be true in order for stage to execute. Since they happen to be the same in the case of a tag checkout, this condition setup is always false.

The solution depends on what you want to achieve. If you wish to execute the stage if any of those is true, the condition should read:

```
when {
    anyOf {
        branch 'master'
        tag 'v*'
    }
}
```

If you just wish to run on *v** tags, I would just drop *branch* condition entirely.